# Want to install pre existing ubuntu OS into parallels on windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

My question is, is it possible? I don't have an external hardrive, or anyway to back up my existing ubuntu OS. I thought of copying my ENTIRE ubuntu file system directly over to my Windows side, since you can mount the Windows OS in ubuntu 12.04, but it says I don't have permission, but I'm admin of my computer. So is there another way? Or maybe a fix?

Comment: What is exactly meant by "since you can mount the Windows OS in ubuntu 12.04"? Your question is not very clear. Can you please try and express it in different words?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 let's you access your windows file system from the Ubuntu home folder. It's shows up like a mountable storage device on the side bar, usually named whatever space you allocated for it, mine is called "160 GB system storage." What I'm trying to do is copy my entire Ubuntu file system to my windows partition, wipe my Ubuntu partition and reinstall it in parallels to make it more convenient than having to restart my laptop every time I want to use Ubuntu or windows. The problem I'm having is even though in admin, It won't let me copy it because I'm not "root."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows and Ubuntu have to reside on two different disk partitions, since their file systems work on different file formatting :

- Windows on FAT32 or NTFS
- Ubuntu on ext3 / ext4 or such formatting standard.

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to switch between Windows and Ubuntu OS without having to restart your PC. I am afraid, this is not possible since both will have to reside on two different partitions and only one of them can be booted at a time.

**Note :** Best possible solution for you could be to use [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Windows as a virtual machine. You can then easily power up that machine without having to shut down Ubuntu.